# DNS lookups using pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am writing a program that parses HTML, however, while it parses multiple HTML files, I need to perform DNS lookups on a collection of IPs. I was thinking to use `pthreads` for the lookups task.

Would you recommend doing it this way? Do I need more than one thread for this task? What are some of the potential problems I could run into? Any feedback is appreciated.

This is what I was thinking...

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *ip2host(void *ips[][2]){
    struct hostent *hent;
    struct in_addr addr;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        if(!inet_aton(ips[i][0], &addr))
            return NULL;

        if((hent = gethostbyaddr((char *)&(addr.s_addr), sizeof(addr.s_addr), AF_INET))){
            ips[i][1] = malloc (strlen (hent->h_name) + 1);
            strcpy(ips[i][1], hent->h_name);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    char *ips[][2] = {
        {"199.21.99.110", NULL},
        {"66.249.73.55", NULL},
        {"74.125.225.34", NULL}
    };

    pthread_t thread1;
    if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, ip2host, &ips)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // parse html files
    int y = 0;
    while(++y < 100000);
    printf("y increment finished\n");

    if(pthread_join(thread1, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ips[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may find it easier to do DNS lookups asynchronously with e.g. c-ares (http://c-ares.haxx.se/).

Comment: Seems to be an interesting library. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: There are actually a few good libraries that do this, since it's a common problem.  Primitive DNS lookup is also bundled into libevent/libev.

Comment: If you are going to thread off the DNS query, may as well thread off the entire DNS/connect/read/parse operation.  Declare a struct that contains the URL, socket, read buffers, parse vars and eveything else needed for the operations.  Make one, fill in the URL, pass its pointer to the thread, (or thread pool queue).

Comment: Verbatim from `man 3 gethostbyaddr`: "*The gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() functions are obsolete. Applications should use getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.*"

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the DNS lookup as part of the connection process and do it before the `connect()`. Thats where you need it anyway, whats the point in doing it in another thread if the IP may not be ready at the moment you need it?

Remember `connect()` will hang your thread until the connection is stabilished too, so resolving IPs is not the only time expending stuff here.

Also, don't worry about caching DNS resolutions, the system itself will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

gethostbyaddr is not thread safe because it returns a pointer to a static struct. If you're using gcc, you can use gethostbyaddr_r which is a thread-safe extension.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this!